# Creating a windows service to display timer on the top right position in UWP app

Tags: uwp, windows-services, surface-hub

I am developing an app for Microsoft `surface hub`. I have a requirement wherein when the user clicks on a button , there is a countdown timer running on the desktop of the `surface hub`. The timer is not the part of the app but the app can start and stop the timer .
Even if my app is minimized , the timer should be shown ticking on the `top right` corner of the `Surface Hub`.

As far as I understand that the timer can be a part of the UWP app and when the app is minimized or in the background , the timer wouldn't be visible . My requirements ask me to display the timer if the user selects `"show timer"` from my app and it doesn't have to be a part of the app but can be controlled by the user.
How is this possible in `UWP` and is running a `windows service` can help?
I am completely new to this and seeking some advice and some samples that go well with the `UWP` app

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Picture in Picture mode](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/universal-windows-app-model/2017/02/11/compactoverlay-mode-aka-picture-in-picture/) to show your app above other windows. AFAIK this is the only way how to do something like an overlay.

Comment: I feel like this would help ? can I define the size of the overlay window and actions like how to bring back the app in the "running" state?